# ¿Cómo ordenar correctamente elementos en grid bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, web, diseño

[image: tarjetas de bootstrap]

Tengo los dos primeras elementos de bootstrap dentro de una row, y el tercero está afuera, cada una es independiente de la otra,  todo bien cuando en la tarjeta de "lista de pagos realizados" no tiene muchos items, pero cuando crece va empujando hacia abajo la tarjeta de abajo, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo distribuir las cards para que la 1 y la 2 sean independientes(pero que queden acomodadas de la misma manera) y que la 3 card se mantenga en su posición a pesar del tamaño de la 2 card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que quieres conseguir sería más apropiado tener dos columnas, una con las tarjetas de *Información del cliente* y *Nuevo pago* y la otra con *Lista de pagos realizados*. De esa manera, aunque esta última crezca, no va afectar a la posición de las otras dos.

```css
#informacion-cliente {
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px
}

#nuevo-pago {
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80%;
}

#lista-pagos-realizados {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <section id="informacion-cliente">
        <p>Información del cliente</p>
      </section>
      <section id="nuevo-pago">
        <p>Nuevo pago</p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <section id="lista-pagos-realizados">
        <p>Listado de pagos realizados</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificando el css de la clase card

```
.card2{
 max-height: 300px;
}
```

o cuanto desees, para que no ocupe toda la pantalla mientras va llenando los datos